# CSRF token not sent from Angular to Spring

Tags: spring, angular, security, spring-boot, csrf

We are building a web application using Angular and Spring Boot. As one of our security measures, we use CSRF tokens. The issue is that, on our local machines, the token validation works, but on our staging server, the tokens aren't sent by the frontend. The problem has suddenly occurred; we didn't have this problem for the first few months of using the tokens. After a certain build, they started failing. Then after a while, they were working again, but now have ceased working once more.

So, it seems like there is an environment issue that we fail to see.

### What we can see

Spring is creating the CSRF token and sending it on preflight (OPTIONS) requests. It encapsulates the token in the Set-Cookie header, which Angular reads using the CookieXSRFStrategy. Again, locally this works fine, but on our staging server this fails. The issue is that Angular doesn't set the cookie after receiving the token. We checked this by inspecting the cookies in the Google Dev Console.

The specific error given by Spring is:

> Invalid CSRF Token was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or
>   header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'

### The issue this causes

We can't login, since Spring doesn't receive a CSRF token. Therefore we can't do anything with the application unless we turn off CSRF protection completely.

### We have tried

- Specifically whitelisting cookies for the application in Chrome.
- Clearing cookies and cache.
- Trying in different browsers, on different machines. This happens in Chrome, IE11 and Firefox. We haven't tried any other browsers.
- Making sure the origin is allowed through CORS, which it is. We do this with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
- Exposing more headers, like Set-Cookie using the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header. This doesn't change anything.
- Allowing more headers, using Access-Control-Allow-Headers. This doesn't change anything either.
- Simulating the login process using cURL (with the Postman application). This works. So it's an issue of Angular not being able to process the token properly.
- Reading the headers manually with JavaScript/TypeScript. This didn't seem to work since the header wasn't exposed.
- After struggling with the issue, we decided to integrate Docker, in an effort to mirror our staging and local environments. This didn't resolve the issue.
- Reverting back to a previous build didn't work either.

### Important notes

- Both locally and on the staging environment we use an SSL certificate. Locally, we use a self-signed certificate.
- All of the application runs on a Wildfly server. Both the Angular and Spring code is built and distributed using WAR files, which Wildfly deploys.
- We are using a corporate proxy. The staging server is hosted in-house, and is only accessible when you're on the corporate network.

### Versions

- Angular: 4.2.2
- Spring Boot: 1.4.1
- Wildfly: 10.1.0.Final

Our current workaround is that we have disabled CSRF protection completely, so as to be able to continue development while we are looking for a solution.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The exception *Invalid CSRF Token was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'* occurs when **an invalid** CSRF token is passed. If Spring would receive no CSRF token at all, it would print a different message "Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found." That means frontend is sending old or invalid CSRF token.

1. Possibly your corporate network proxy applies some login mechanism and override your X-CSRF-TOKEN header.
2. According to [Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-cookie), cookieHttpOnly=false is needed to allow AngularJS to read the XSRF-TOKEN cookie.